# That and which with plurals

Tags: relative-pronouns, restrictive-clauses

Here is a sentence in which I've used 'that' and 'which' with plurals (apples)

> I have twenty apples which/that aren't mine.

Is it equally correct in grammar to use "which are" and "that are" with plurals (for example: *apples*)? Do they (*that are* and *which are*) convey the same meaning?

Comment: The difference between *that* and *which* is **not affected by whether the noun  is singular or plural**

Comment: The question which is identified as a duplicate does not address singulars or plurals at all. Yes, the poster here really asked two questions: Can that/which be used with plurals? and Do they mean the same thing? His second question may be answered by the referenced question, but his first, and what's apparently his main question because it's the one he put in the title, is not.

Answer (score 0):

Both "that" and "which" can be used with either a singular or a plural.

In this context, they mean the same thing.